# Listing a linked list

Tags: c

I wrote a program. It takes data from a text file to a linked list word by word. But there is a problem at listing the words.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct list
{
    char *data;
    struct list *next;
} node;

int main()
{
    int i;
    char *word = NULL;
    char line[1000];
    node *root,*temp;

    root = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp = root;
    FILE *f = fopen("test.txt","r");
    while (fgets( line, sizeof(line), f ))
        for (word = strtok(line, " "); word; word = strtok(NULL, " "))
        {
            temp->data = word;
            temp->next=(node *) malloc(sizeof(node));
            temp=temp->next;
        }
    fclose(f);
    temp =root;
    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n",temp->data);
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You really should state what the problem is if you want help. However, if it were me, I'd make sure that the parsing and building of the list is correct. Seems more likely to be the problem than the listing is.

Comment: It looks like he is reusing the line array for each line. So he only sees his words from the last line, if everything else is working correctly.

Comment: You're only seeing 10 words because of "for(i=0; i<10; i++)", should be "while(temp)" instead. For that, the list needs to be null-terminated. Therefore in your main loop, add "temp->next->next = 0;" immediately after the malloc.

Answer (score 3):

From 'man strtok':

> Be cautious when using these
>   functions.  If you do use them, note
>   that:
>
> ```
>    * These functions modify their first argument.
>    * These functions cannot be used on constant strings.
>    * The identity of the delimiting character is lost.
> ```

So you need to allocate new memory for each word because the pointers returned by strtok are indexing into the line array.

This is best illustrated by changing the code to:

```
...
  while (fgets( line, sizeof(line), f )) {
    printf("%s\n",line);
    for (word = strtok(line, " "); word; word = strtok(NULL, " ")) {
      printf("%p\n",word);
      temp->data = word;
...
```

Which when run on the following input:

```
check default for switches 
throw stmts to exit node
```

prints the following:

```
check default for switches

0x7fff94e0bf70
0x7fff94e0bf76
0x7fff94e0bf7e
0x7fff94e0bf82
throw stmts to exit node

0x7fff94e0bf70
0x7fff94e0bf76
0x7fff94e0bf7c
0x7fff94e0bf7f
0x7fff94e0bf84
throw
stmts

t
throw
stmts
to
exit
node
```

Notice that the pointer for the first word in each line is the same.